# C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\javac.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, cmd

Thanks very much for your help. **So here is what I’m trying to do:**

I am trying to use Jenkins for the first time, but every time a build is run it gives me an error that reads:

```
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error: [ERROR] '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\javac.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

It’s looking for javac.exe in the wrong folder as it’s actually inside C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe (Inside the bin folder)

[image]

Every tutorial I read on the internet asks me to do this set up inside the System Variables and I think I’ve done every single combination of those. (I know there's plenty of SO questions similar to these one but unfortunately I haven't been able to fix my issue using their solution). That’s what I have at the moment:

[image]

*System Variables*
[image]

*User Variables*
[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone could please point out what I'm doing wrong that would be really very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what was causing the problem. This line on the project POM was the one with the wrong JDK path:

[image]

Thanks for the help anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a lot of variables there. Are those your system or user environment variables? Use the system environment variables.

- Check your java path (go to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02" and copy the address).
- Go to your **System** Environment Variables and create a new one called JAVA_HOME.
- Insert "%JAVA_HOME%\bin" at **the beginning** of the Path variable followed by semicolon
- Close and reopen your command prompt

Comment: Hi @ben Thanks for your reply. I've edited the description of the issue according to your question. The first image is the System Variables and the second one is the User Variables. I moved the /bin java variable to the beginning of the path but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add it in environment variable and add the link where JDK bin is in the PATH

Comment: Hi @Omar. Thanks for your reply. I think that's what I have already as per the screenshots sent. If not, could you please provide a more detailed explanation on what is wrong with what I have and what should be changes, please? Thanks again.